# How to sort Grid view on the basis of particular column?

Tags: c#, gridview, sorting

I want to sort Grid View on the basis of paticular column.

For example:

[alt text http://img30.imageshack.us/img30/5673/tablezz.jpg](http://img30.imageshack.us/img30/5673/tablezz.jpg)

Now i want to sort above table in such a way that all Developers should come first.

Thanx

Answer (score 0):

First set the Allowsorting Property of the Gridview to true.

Then set the SortExpression property of the Occupation column to correponding column of your data source.

For example:

```
yourGridView.Columns[2].SortExpression = "YourDataSourceColumnName"
```